# Do HTML5 Web Workers finish if the user leaves or closes browser?

Tags: html, web-worker

If a web worker starts and then the user goes to another page or closes their browser, does the web worker still finish?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What happens to an HTML5 web worker thread when the tab is closed while it's running?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875310/what-happens-to-an-html5-web-worker-thread-when-the-tab-is-closed-while-its-run)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The worker will terminate once all owners have been closed. If you have a shared worker it will stay alive until all owners are closed (it could exist in another tab, for example). Closing the browser will kill all workers always.

Answer (score 0):

The web worker stops when the browser closes, since its not running on an external server.

---

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875310/what-happens-to-an-html5-web-worker-thread-when-the-tab-is-closed-while-its-run)