Sending requests after closing the browser tab
I have a system with Laravel on the backend and React on the frontend. It’s a workplace system, and I have a chat with user status functionality. I want to update the user's status to offline after they close the browser tab, but I can't get it to work. I've already tried using window.addEventListener('beforeunload'), but once the tab is closed, it's not possible to send requests. Does anyone know a way to achieve this?
BACKEND:
public function updateStatus(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'status' => 'required|string|in:online,disconnected,away'
        ]);

        $user = auth()->user();
        $status = $request->status;
        $user->chat_status = $status;
        $user->save();

        return response()->json(['message' => 'Status atualizado com sucesso.']);
    }

FRONTEND:
const updateStatus = async (status) => {
        try {
            await api.post('/api/user/status', { status });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Erro ao atualizar status:', error);
        }
    };

    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
        updateStatus('online');
    });

    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => {
        updateStatus('disconnected');
    });


You can't send requests from a page that isn't running.  But one thing you can do is send periodic requests when the page is running, and those requests indicate to your server that the page is still in the browser and running.  When those requests stop, the user is offline.

You can try implementing a service worker. Check this post, you might find something useful https://stackoverflow.com/a/46281372/247672 . Also,
"Note that the sync event can be delivered even if the user has left the application, making it much more effective than the traditional method of retrying failed requests." https://developer.chrome.com/docs/workbox/modules/workbox-background-sync

Might also be worth looking into: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Beacon_API
